# Arrange sf object features according to adjacency

Tags: r, r-sf

Suppose I have a `MULTILINESTRING` named `m_line` composed of several `MULTILINESTRINGs`.

```
l1 = st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(0,1),c(1,10))))
l2 = st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(1,10),c(40,25))))
l3 = st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(40,25),c(50,40))))
l4 = st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(50,40),c(21,63))))


l1 = st_sf(geometry=st_sfc(l1, crs=3857))
l2 = st_sf(geometry=st_sfc(l2, crs=3857))
l3 = st_sf(geometry=st_sfc(l3, crs=3857))
l4 = st_sf(geometry=st_sfc(l4, crs=3857))

m_line = rbind(l4,l2,l1,l3)
```

Is there a way to arrange the features so that the 1st feature is either end of the line then the 2nd feature is the line adjacent to the 1st feature and so on? Just like making it rearrange into l1,l2,l3,l4 or l4,l3,l2,l1.

Thank you in advance and have a great day!

Comment: As described, that would just be plot order, `plot(m_line)` vs `plot(rev(m_line))`. Though I guess you have something more in mind given your `either end`, but as where a line is is determined by a given line's coords, except for renaming (l1 is now l2) or changing the coords...? Could you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Chris, hope you're doing great, and thanks for replying. Actually, I'm working on a multilinestring composed of at least 200k smaller multilinestrings, however for some reason, probably the individual line segments that make up the entire line were edited/replaced, thus the order in which the features appear (in the attributes table) was random. Like in my example `m_line`, the order is l4,l2,l1,l3. However, I wanted to arrange them to either l1,l2,l3,l4, or the reverse. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that under a couple assumptions - such as that all your "small lines" form a single "long line", with no discontinuity and no forks - you could calculate a vector ordering the small linestrings according to adjacency matrix. Which can be calculated via a `sf::st_touches()` call.

```
# adjacency matrix of line with itself
adjacency <- st_touches(m_line, m_line)

# first element that has only a 1 neighbor - a good place to start
wrk_item <- min(which(sapply(adjacency, length) == 1)) 

# init  of resultset
order <- rep(NA, length(adjacency))


# iterate over adjacency matrix, constructing the final version of order vector
for (i in seq_along(adjacency)) {
  
  # update resultset
  order[i] <- wrk_item
  
  # next item yet unprocessed (= not yet in resultset)
  wrk_item <- setdiff(adjacency[[i]], order)
  
}

order
# [1] 1 4 3 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an error when I tried working on more features than my example.

Based on Jindra's solution, I tweaked it a bit. I also started finding the feature that is connected in one end only. Then, I looped through all the features to find the next feature that is adjacent to the previous feature identified.

Here's my solution.

```
library(sf)

l1 = st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(0,1),c(1,10))))
l2 = st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(1,10),c(40,25))))
l3 = st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(40,25),c(50,40))))
l4 = st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(50,40),c(21,63))))
l5 = st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(21,63),c(33,75))))
l6 = st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(33,75),c(75,85))))
l7 = st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(75,85),c(75,90))))
l8 = st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(75,90),c(82,100))))


l1 = st_sf(geometry=st_sfc(l1, crs=3857))
l2 = st_sf(geometry=st_sfc(l2, crs=3857))
l3 = st_sf(geometry=st_sfc(l3, crs=3857))
l4 = st_sf(geometry=st_sfc(l4, crs=3857))
l5 = st_sf(geometry=st_sfc(l5, crs=3857))
l6 = st_sf(geometry=st_sfc(l6, crs=3857))
l7 = st_sf(geometry=st_sfc(l7, crs=3857))
l8 = st_sf(geometry=st_sfc(l8, crs=3857))

m_line = rbind(l4,l2,l5,l7,l1,l3,l8,l6)

adjacency <- st_touches(m_line)
# Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 8, where the predicate was `touches'
#  1: 3, 6
#  2: 5, 6
#  3: 1, 8
#  4: 7, 8
#  5: 2
#  6: 1, 2
#  7: 4
#  8: 3, 4

# get the feature connected to only one end
wrk_item <- min(which(sapply(adjacency, length) == 1)) 

# init  of resultset
order <- rep(NA, length(adjacency)) 

for (i in seq_along(adjacency)) {
  order[i] = wrk_item
  
  #locate the feature that is connected to the current `wrk_item` identified
  adjacency = st_touches(m_line,m_line[wrk_item,])
  
  #if the adjacency returns more than one value then select the one that is not in the resultset
  wrk_item = setdiff(which(sapply(adjacency, is.na) == FALSE),order)
  
}

order
# [1] 5 2 6 1 3 8 4 7

#rearrange the features based on adjacency
m_line2 = m_line[order,]

st_coordinates(m_line2)
#       X   Y L1 L2
# [1,]  0   1  1  1
# [2,]  1  10  1  1
# [3,]  1  10  1  2
# [4,] 40  25  1  2
# [5,] 40  25  1  3
# [6,] 50  40  1  3
# [7,] 50  40  1  4
# [8,] 21  63  1  4
# [9,] 21  63  1  5
# [10,] 33  75  1  5
# [11,] 33  75  1  6
# [12,] 75  85  1  6
# [13,] 75  85  1  7
# [14,] 75  90  1  7
# [15,] 75  90  1  8
# [16,] 82 100  1  8

st_coordinates(m_line)
#       X   Y L1 L2
# [1,] 50  40  1  1
# [2,] 21  63  1  1
# [3,]  1  10  1  2
# [4,] 40  25  1  2
# [5,] 21  63  1  3
# [6,] 33  75  1  3
# [7,] 75  85  1  4
# [8,] 75  90  1  4
# [9,]  0   1  1  5
# [10,]  1  10  1  5
# [11,] 40  25  1  6
# [12,] 50  40  1  6
# [13,] 75  90  1  7
# [14,] 82 100  1  7
# [15,] 33  75  1  8
# [16,] 75  85  1  8
```